# Read environment variables in revel app.conf

Tags: go, config, revel

Revel uses app.conf for storing configuration. I want my configuration to get value from environment variable using `os.Getenv(key)`

How can I do it? Should I use revel.Config to make changes? if so where do I place it?

Or is there another way?

I use it mainly for storing database information (I don't want to enter my credential in configuration files)

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Revel](http://revel.github.io/) uses [revel/config](https://github.com/revel/config) for managing [`app.conf`](https://revel.github.io/manual/appconf.html).

And the *only* place revel/config foes read from the environment variable is in [`type.go (c *Config) String()`](https://github.com/revel/config/blob/09efbd4617d1beb41b72f6668403b1e383b6a4cf/type.go#L155-L156) method.

```
// $ environment variables
computedVal, _ = c.computeVar(&value, envVarRegExp, 2, 1, func(varName *string) string {
return os.Getenv(*varName)
})
```

That means you could add in a config file values based on the name of environment variable, which would allow you to use said environment variable to modify the config.

See an example in the [`revel/config REAMD.md` file](https://github.com/revel/config/blob/master/README.md#operating-instructions).

```
[DEFAULT]
host: www.example.com
protocol: http://
base-url: %(protocol)s%(host)s    <====
```

---

The [OP pveyes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2723222/pveyes) [points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23714707/read-environment-variables-in-revel-app-conf#comment36456930_23715510) to [this comment in `type.go`](https://github.com/revel/config/blob/09efbd4617d1beb41b72f6668403b1e383b6a4cf/type.go#L43-L45):

```
// substitute by new value and take off leading '%(' and trailing ')s'
// %(foo)s => headsz=2, tailsz=2
// ${foo} => headsz=2, tailsz=1
```

So:

> - when using environment variables use `${ENV_VARS}`, and
> - for unfolding variables use `%(UNF_VARS)s`

Comment: Thanks, they should made it clearer in their README, when using environment variables use ${ENV_VARS}, and for unfolding variables use %(UNF_VARS)s as described in https://github.com/revel/config/blob/09efbd4617d1beb41b72f6668403b1e383b6a4cf/type.go#L43-L45

Comment: @pveyes Very true. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.